# Is Flask-Marshmallow's init_app() actually necessary?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, marshmallow

The [Flask-Marshmallow documentation](https://flask-marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#flask_marshmallow.Marshmallow.init_app) has this to say about `Marshmallow.init_app()`

> Initializes the application with the extension.

The [code behind it](https://github.com/marshmallow-code/flask-marshmallow/blob/7208b900ecdac881d272378c4ef1482741fe7b9b/flask_marshmallow/__init__.py#L117) seems to do something important related to SQLAlchemy session management:

```
def init_app(self, app):
    app.extensions = getattr(app, 'extensions', {})

    # If using Flask-SQLAlchemy, attach db.session to ModelSchema
    if has_sqla and 'sqlalchemy' in app.extensions:
        db = app.extensions['sqlalchemy'].db
        self.ModelSchema.OPTIONS_CLASS.session = db.session
    app.extensions[EXTENSION_NAME] = self
```

but I've been using and developing my application for a while without including a call to `init_app` anywhere, and it's seemingly worked fine. I am using SQLAlchemy, Flask-SQLAlchemy, and Marshmallow-SQLAlchemy (as well as Flask-Marshmallow).

What problems am I causing by not doing `ma.init_app(app)`, and why does everything seem to work anyway?

Currently, I have a `database` and a `schema` module; `database` looks something like this:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

class Customer(db.Model):
    ...
```

and `schema` like this:

```
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow
from database import Customer

ma = Marshmallow()

class CustomerSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
```

In my top-level `__init__.py`, I'm doing this:

```
from flask import Flask
from database import db

app = Flask(__name__)
db.init_app(app)
with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()
```

---

Here is an MVCE (put in `mvce/__init__.py`, run with `PYTHONPATH=. FLASK_APP=mvce flask run`, then make a POST request to localhost:5000 with the `name` form field set to something and then make a GET request to see that the `Customer` got committed to the database correctly):

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///database.db"

@app.route("/")
def get():
    return CustomerSchema(many=True).jsonify(Customer.query.all())
@app.route("/", methods=["POST"])
def new():
    customer, errors = CustomerSchema().load(request.form)
    if errors:
        return errors, 400
    db.session.add(customer)
    db.session.commit()
    return CustomerSchema().jsonify(customer)

db = SQLAlchemy()
class Customer(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)

ma = Marshmallow()  # Not passing `app`
class CustomerSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer

db.init_app(app)
with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()
# Note that we don't ever call `ma.init_app(app)`!
```

Comment: How are you currently initializing Marshmallow in your Flask app? Like so `ma = Marshmallow(app)`?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule At the moment I'm doing `ma = Marshmallow()` (it's in a separate module, so I don't have access to `app`).

Comment: If you think you need to build your api schema from your models by subclassing `ma.ModelSchema` then you need to initialize your application using `ma.init_app` passing it the `Flask` instance. I assume you're currently just using `ma.Schema`.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule Nope, I'm using ModelSchema. I've updated the question with some code.

Comment: @Josh are you using `schema.load`? if you do this without calling Flask-Marshmallow 's `init_app` you would get an error.

Comment: @georgexsh Yes, I'm calling `schema.load`; I've added an MVCE to the question.

Comment: @Josh with your example, I got an error as expected: `AttributeError: 'DummySession' object has no attribute 'query'`, and calling `ma.init_app(app)` would fix it.

Comment: @Josh Note that I am using flask-marshmallow 0.8.0.

Comment: @georgexsh I'm using the same version of Flask-Marshmallow, but I don't get an error when doing `http -f POST localhost:5000 name=tim`. I do get that error if I specify an `id` in the request (`http -f POST localhost:5000 id=42 name=eric`), but I get that error even if I do `ma.init_app(app)` at the end! It looks like I have to init both the flask-sqlalchemy `db` *and* the flask-marshmallow `ma` before I can define any schemas? How am I supposed to avoid declaring everything in `__init__.py`? Should I put `app = Flask("myapp")` in myapp/app.py, then `from myapp.app import app` everywhere else?

Comment: @Josh to both of your questions, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To summarise the comments on the question (many thanks to [georgexsh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4201810/georgexsh)):

Yes, `init_app` is required, otherwise you'll get errors when you try to `schema.load()` something with a primary key. Further, it has to be called before you create any schemas, and it must be called after you've done the same to your (Flask-SQLAlchemy) database object. IOW, you have to do things in this order:

```
db = flask_sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemy()
ma = flask_marshmallow.Marshmallow()
db.init_app(app)
ma.init_app(app)
class CustomerSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    ...
```

so it's probably easier to just pass `app` directly to the constructors:

```
db = flask_sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemy(app)
ma = flask_marshmallow.Marshmallow(app)
```

If your application architecture makes this tricky (e.g. you define `app` in `myapp/__init__.py`, but database models in `myapp/database.py` and schemas in `myapp/schema.py`), you can move your definition of `app` to a separate module, e.g. `myapp/app.py`, and then do something like

```
from myapp.app import app
db = flask_sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemy(app)
```

anywhere you need to use it.

Comment: are you shure about it?, i have done a load with a model with primary key without init the Marshmallow and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Calling `flask_marshmallow.Marshmallow.init_app()` will bound the scoped session created by Flask-SQLAlchemy to `flask_marshmallow.ModelSchema`, `flask_marshmallow.ModelSchema` is identical with `marshmallow_sqlalchemy.ModelSchema`, but save you from manually passing session object.

`flask_marshmallow.ModelSchema` could [generate schema fields from existing SQLAlchemy model](http://marshmallow-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes.html) for you, and deserialize data into SQLAlchemy model directly. If you do not use this feature, you probably don't need Flask-Marshmallow at all, but I recommend using it, calling Flask-Marshmallow 's `init_app` is necessary for using `ModelSchema().load`.